# htaccess RewriteCond RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I already have website www.example.com which resides in /public_html/site.

Now I want to point www.example.com/anothersite to /public_html/anothersite.

How can I?

The .htaccess in /public_html:

```
RewriteOptions inherit

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !site/
RewriteRule (.*) /site/$1 [L]
```

The .htaccess in /public_html/site:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /site/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

In The .htaccess in /public_html I have tried this but it says error 404 Page not found!:

```
RewriteOptions inherit

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteRule ^anothersite/(.*)$ http://example.com/anothersite/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !site/
RewriteRule (.*) /site/$1 [L]
```

But I dont know why it was not working last but now its working with the above code...

Answer (score 0):

The .htaccess in /public_html:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (?!^(?:site|anothersite)(?:/.*|)$)^.*$ /site%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: In the htaccess you have given will point both of example.com/site and example.com/anothersite to /public_html/site. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes above rule will skip `/anothersite` and by default `http://site.com/anothersite` will load `/anothersite`

Comment: But its not working. http://example.com/anothersite pointing to http://example.com/site also

Comment: Could be trailing slash issue. Have you tried `http://example.com/anothersite/` ?